# Count Consecutive Numbers in Column

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am looking to count the occurrences of consecutive numbers in a column and cannot seem to find a logical way to calculate this within a loop.

My column of values is simply entries of 0 or 1. What I want to is count each time there is two 0's in a row, three 0's a row, four 0's in a row and so on. The maximum number of times I would expect a consecutive number is 15.

Ideally, I would like the output for each occurrence entered into a table.
I have provided a snapshot below of the column in question.

My attempts so far consist of looping through the column checking for two 0's in a row, starting at row 2 but this causes issues when I have more than two 0's in a row.

```
'Check for 2
Dim TwoCount, RowNo As Integer, LastRow As Long
LastRow = Sheets("Data").Range("A165536").End(xlUp).Row
TwoCount = 0
RowNo = 2
For i = 2 To LastRow
If Sheets("Data").Range("H" & RowNo).Value = 1 Then
RowNo = RowNo + 1
Else
If Sheets("Data").Range("H" & RowNo).Value = 0 Then
TwoCount = 1
RowNo = RowNo + 1
    If Sheets("Data").Range("H" & RowNo).Value = 0 Then
    TwoCount = 2
    RowNo = RowNo + 1
If Sheets("Data").Range("H" & RowNo).Value = 1 Then
End If
End If
End If
End If
Next i
```

[image]

I welcome any suggestions to how I should approach this? Whether it's easier as a formula or array formula.

Desired output

[image]

Comment: So how would your output have to look like? `3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 6, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 6`? Then your question was already asked. See link above your question.

Comment: That output isn't really what I'm looking for. I was after a a list of something more along the lines of this - Updated the original question to show the output

Comment: So you want to count how many times a `1` occurs and how many times a `2` occurs? Sorry the output you post is still not clear as it does not match the input data you showed.

Comment: Apologies, occurrences of 0 in that output table - I've updated the snapshot

Comment: So to summarize: you are only interested in the zeros. And you want how many times there is `1` consecutive zero, how many times there is `2` consecutive zeros and so on. You don't care about any other numbers in the data but only zeros? Was that correct?

Comment: Here is a question; what if there is a sequence of 4 zeros? Would you count a 1, a 2 a 3 and a 4 times, **or** just the 4 times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Count Consecutive Occurrences

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CountConsecutive()
    
    ' Source
    Const sName As String = "Data"
    Const sFirstCellAddress As String = "H1"
    Const sCriteria As Variant = 0
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "Data"
    Const dFirstCellAddress As String = "J1"
    Dim dHeaders As Variant
    dHeaders = VBA.Array("Occurrences", "Number of Times")
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Write the values from the source column to an array.
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    
    Dim Data As Variant
    Dim rCount As Long
    
    With sws.Range(sFirstCellAddress)
        Dim slCell As Range: Set slCell = .Resize(sws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If slCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        rCount = slCell.Row - .Row + 1
        If rCount < 2 Then Exit Sub
        Data = .Resize(rCount).Value
    End With
        
    ' Count the occurrences by using a dictionary.
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim Key As Long
    Dim r As Long
    Dim cCount As Long
    Dim MaxCount As Long
    
    For r = 2 To rCount
        Key = Data(r, 1)
        If IsNumeric(Key) Then
            If Key = sCriteria Then
                cCount = cCount + 1
            Else
                If cCount > 0 Then
                    dict(cCount) = dict(cCount) + 1
                    If cCount > MaxCount Then MaxCount = cCount
                    cCount = 0
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    If MaxCount = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Write the values from the dictionary to the array.
    
    rCount = MaxCount + 1
    ReDim Data(1 To rCount, 1 To 2)
    
    Data(1, 1) = dHeaders(0)
    Data(1, 2) = dHeaders(1)
    
    For r = 2 To rCount
        Data(r, 1) = r - 1
        If dict.Exists(r - 1) Then
            Data(r, 2) = dict(r - 1)
        Else
            Data(r, 2) = 0
        End If
    Next r
    
    ' Write the values from the array to the destination range.
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    With dws.Range(dFirstCellAddress).Resize(, 2)
        .Resize(rCount).Value = Data
        .Resize(dws.Rows.Count - .Row - rCount + 1).Offset(rCount).Clear
        '.Font.Bold = True
        '.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
    
    'wb.save
    
    MsgBox "Consecutive count created.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

### COUNTING THE FREQUENCY OF CONSECUTIVE OCCURRENCES OF 0 IN A COLUMN

You may try this array formula as well,

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

• Formula used in cell **L2**

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(FREQUENCY(
IF($H$2:$H$32=0,ROW($H$2:$H$32)),
IF($H$2:$H$32=1,ROW($H$2:$H$32)))=K2))
```

And **Fill Down**!

**Note:** Array formulas need to be entered by pressing `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `ENTER` (not just `ENTER`). Hold down both the `CTRL` key and the `SHIFT` key then hit `ENTER`. If you are using **Excel 2021** or **O365** you can only press `ENTER`.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine your numbers `Win/Lose` in column A then add in cell **B3** (not B2 this will stay empty) the following formula and copy it down:

```
=IF(AND(A3=0,A3<>A4),COUNTIF($A$2:A3,A3)-SUM($B$2:B2),"")
```

Then to count them just use `=COUNTIF(B:B,E2)` in F2 and copy it down.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can read this requirements in two ways as I see it:

- You can count an occurence of 1,2,3 and 4 in a sequence of 4 zero's;
- You can count only the max occurence of the above;

I went with the assumptions of the latter:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=LET(X,SEQUENCE(15),Y,LEN(TEXTSPLIT(CONCAT(IF(A2:A32," ",1)),," ",1)),VSTACK({"Occurences of 0","Number of Times"},HSTACK(X,BYROW(X,LAMBDA(a,SUM(--(Y=a)))))))
```

---

**Important note**:

It may not be best to rely on `CONCAT()` since depending on the amount of rows you want to concatenate, it may strike a character limit. Instead you could try something like:

```
=LET(X,SEQUENCE(15),Y,LEN(TEXTSPLIT(REDUCE("",A2:A32,LAMBDA(a,b,a&IF(b," ",1))),," ",1)),VSTACK({"Occurences of 0","Number of Times"},HSTACK(X,BYROW(X,LAMBDA(a,SUM(--(Y=a)))))))
```

---

Also, please note that ms365 is required for the above functions to run properly (and at time of writing [`VSTACK()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vstack-function-a4b86897-be0f-48fc-adca-fcc10d795a9c), [`HSTACK()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hstack-function-98c4ab76-10fe-4b4f-8d5f-af1c125fe8c2) and [`TEXTSPLIT()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textsplit-function-b1ca414e-4c21-4ca0-b1b7-bdecace8a6e7) are still in the insider's BETA-channels.

Comment: Can't wait to get access to those. Nice approach!